Error message: "GET /blog/about HTTP/1.1" 404 Not Found: /blog/about geting this while creating Blog app
views.py:
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse

def home(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog home</h1>')

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h1>Blog About</h1>')

urls.py (in blog):
from django.urls import path
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.home, name='blog-home'),
    path('about/', views.about, name='blog-about'),
]

urls.py (in django_project):
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]

can't get the aboutpage
Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/about
Using the URLconf defined in django_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

admin/
blog/ [name='blog-home']

The current path, blog/about, didn’t match any of these.
trying to get the about page but couln't found
resulted:Page not found (404)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/about
Using the URLconf defined in django_project.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
admin/
blog/ [name='blog-home']
The current path, blog/about, didn’t match any of these.

your code seems right there is no error in your code can you provide the error page.

I'm not able to recreate your error with the code provided.  Please provide a minimal, reproducible example

It is http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/about/ with a trailing slash. If APPEND_SLASH is enabled that is not a problem, otherwise it is.

Your request URL is http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/about but according to your URL conf, the correct request URL should have a trailing slash i.e. http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/about/. As @willeM_ Van Onsem noted in the comments, this should not be an issue if APPEND_SLASH is set to True.
Either add a trailing slash to your request URL or remove the trailing slash in your about URL conf to fix this.
